# CSS animation delay is not working on fadeIn effect. The animation begins immediately regardless of what i set the delay to

Tags: html, css

Basically what the title says. I am trying to get this div to appear about 4s after page load, but it is instead appearing straight away. It is doing the fade animation (which lasts 2 seconds) but this animation is beginning straight away.

Here is the HTML:

```css
.abouttext {
  text-align: center;
  /*color: white; removed for snippet demo*/
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  float: right;
}

#aboutone {
  margin-top: 10px;
  animation: fadeIn ease 2s;
  animation-delay: 5s;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn ease 2s;
  -moz-animation: fadeIn ease 2s;
  -o-animation: fadeIn ease 2s;
  -ms-animation: fadeIn ease 2s;
  z-index: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="abouttext" id="aboutone">
  <p>hello</p>
</div>
```

Any help at all on this would be great. I have googled it for hours but can't seem to work out why it is not working.

p.s I am using this on Chrome.

Comment: remove your prefixed rules or set your animation-delay behind them ... prefix are useless nowdays for animation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you're using prefixes for different browsers and they are **after** the original `animation`, browsers will use their prefixed animation (e.g. browsers using `-webkit` will expect `-webkit-animation-delay`).

You could add `animation-duration` with all separate prefixes or just use `animation-delay` in `animation` all together:

```css
#aboutone {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
  z-index: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  
  /* animation: duration timing-function delay name */
  animation: 2s ease 5s fadeIn;
  -webkit-animation: 2s ease 5s fadeIn;
  -moz-animation: 2s ease 5s fadeIn;
  -o-animation: 2s ease 5s fadeIn;
  -ms-animation: 2s ease 5s fadeIn;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}

@-moz-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}

@-o-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {  opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}

@-ms-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}
```

```html
<div class="abouttext" id="aboutone">
  <p>hello</p>
</div>
```

---

If you want the animation to start (with delay) after the whole body is loaded and not right when user loads the page, you can use `onload` event listener on the `body` (As [this answer to your question says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62503502/10892074))

Comment: This has worked perfectly, thanks for the clear explanation to help to me learn WHY it wasn't working originally as well!

Comment: @RoryInTheShell no problem, glad it works! You can also read other answer that explains how to use animation ***after*** the whole body loads

Answer (score 2):

You can use dom call back with a function in Javascript to wait until the document is loaded, then add the style to the element.

```js
(function() {
    let target = document.querySelector('#aboutone');
    target.style.cssText = "animationDelay: 5s; webkit-animation: fadeIn ease 2s; -moz-animation: fadeIn ease 2s; -o-animation: fadeIn ease 2s; -ms-animation: fadeIn ease 2s;";
});
```

```css
.abouttext {
  text-align: center;
  /*color: white; removed for snippet demo*/
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  float: right;
}

#aboutone {
  margin-top: 10px;
  animation: fadeIn ease 2s;
  z-index: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="abouttext" id="aboutone">
  <p>hello</p>
</div>
```

As Vepthy suggested in comments... you could also add an event listener for the `load`. The load event is fired when the whole page has loaded, including all dependent resources such as stylesheets and images.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
  let target = document.querySelector('#aboutone');
  target.style.cssText = "animationDelay: 5s; webkit-animation: fadeIn ease 2s; -moz-animation: fadeIn ease 2s; -o-animation: fadeIn ease 2s; -ms-animation: fadeIn ease 2s;";
});
```

```css
.abouttext {
  text-align: center;
  /*color: white; removed for snippet demo*/
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  float: right;
}

#aboutone {
  margin-top: 10px;
  animation: fadeIn ease 2s;
  z-index: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="abouttext" id="aboutone">
  <p>hello</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Or they can use even listener `onload` for `body`. Though, the problem is that the delay doesn't work, instead animation starts right away.

Comment: Nice edit. I will include your answer to mine as mine is focused on delay not working. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks both! I have gone with the solution from the other answer as I am trying to learn HTML and CSS right now, before I start learning Javascript. However, much appreciated!

Comment: @RoryInTheShell you can use `onload` in the HTML too ;). In the `body` tag, add the attribute `onload=""`. There, you can add the code from answer above. Though, it will still use JavaScript (DOM) - nothing complicated really.